# Error from action button which invokes flow

Tags: visual-workflow, lightning-action

I have lightning Action button which invokes a flow whenever I click on the action i am getting error

Unfortunately, there was a problem. Please try again. If the problem continues, get in touch with your administrator with the error ID shown here and any other related details. Error ID: 1981567346-45806 (-798260768)

Comment: You need to contact support. There's nothing we can do with this information to assist you.

Answer (score 1):

This is a known issue: [Non-Admins Receiving Internal Server Error when Executing Flow Quick Action](https://success.salesforce.com/issues_view?id=a1p3A000000BMQ8QAO&title=non-admins-receiving-internal-server-error-when-executing-flow-quick-action)

The temporary solution is to grant the end user the "View Setup & Configuration" permission. A fix should be going out this weekend (~Jan 12, 2019).

Comment: Run Flows permission was given. but once i gave manage flows permission to the profile, It works. But to run a flow manage flow permission should not required.

Comment: The fix went out on Saturday, so you should not need to have Manage Flows any longer.